# difference: should sleep or should be sleeping

Tags: modal-verbs, progressive-aspect

In the following sentence, are both "sleep" and "be sleeping" correct? If so, what's the difference?

> When can I leave? I should **sleep** / should **be sleeping** at home now.

Comment: "I should sleep now" is not idiomatic unless it expresses a different meaning (as in "I should go to bed now" [which isn't the case here]). We don't use Present Simple to refer to events that are happening at the moment of speaking

Answer (score 0):

To be honest both sound awkward.

**When can I leave? I should sleep** I would write **When can I leave? I should get some
sleep**

The reference to "get some sleep" means or implies to catch up on your sleep

**When can I leave? I should be sleeping at home now.** I would write **When can I leave? I should be at home, asleep by now.**

**asleep**; adjective [ after verb ] sleeping or not awake:

I'm surprised to see you awake - ten minutes ago you were fast asleep.

**catch/cop/get some** z's

US informal

to sleep:
All I want to do is go home and catch some z's.

Ref CED [asleep](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/asleep) [Get some](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catch-cop-get-some-z-s?q=get%20some)